# How to find the max value of a concave function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

Can anyone help me rewrite the code **without using for-loop**? The goal is the find the spend value that **maximizes** **calcProfit**.

In this example, `calcVolume' & 'calcProfit' are dummy functions. In my real project:

- they are complicated complicated
- 'calcProfit' will be concave
- Running this loop will take > 1 minute (thus undesirable for users)

```
    
set.seed(123)
spend = 150000

unit.x    <- spend/10 # x axis (unit)
max.x     <- spend*2  # x axis (max)

calcVolume <- function(spend) {
  runif(1,0,1)*spend
}

calcProfit <- function(vol) {
  runif(1,0,1)*vol
}
out <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 21, ncol = 2))

cnt <- 1

for (step.x in seq(0, max.x, by = unit.x)) {
  
  out[cnt, 1] <- step.x
  out[cnt, 2] <- calcVolume(step.x) 
  out[cnt, 3] <- calcProfit(out[cnt, 2])
  cnt   <- cnt + 1
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `help("optimize")` or `help("optim")`?

Comment: Not quite. I made an edit to clarify my questions. Yes, I am trying to optimize calcProfit, but it depends on calcVolume. Not sure if we can use 'optimize' to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the functions involved in closed form, then the composite can be optimized with `optimize`.

In the code below I define an auxiliary function `f`.

```r
calcVolume <- function(x) {
  sin(x)
}
# only calcProfit needs to be concave
calcProfit <- function(x) {
  log(x)
}
f <- function(x){
  calcProfit(calcVolume(x))
}

M <- optimize(f, c(0, 3), maximum = TRUE)
M
#> $maximum
#> [1] 1.57078
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] -1.381308e-10

curve(f, 0, 3)
points(M$maximum, M$objective, col = "red", pch = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the order of generating random number, you can try this to avoid the loop.

```
V1 <- seq(0, max.x, by = unit.x)
V2 <- calcVolume(V1)
V3 <- calcProfit(V2)
out <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
```

You can use `which.max` to find the spend value that maximizes calcProfit

```
out[which.max(out$V3),]$V1
```